# Random Points in an n-Dimensional Hypersphere

Tags: matlab, math, geometry

This Matlab code,

> creates a set of random points defined by Cartesian coordinates and
> uniformly distributed over the interior of an n-dimensional
> hypersphere of radius r with center at the origin.

the source is [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9443-random-points-in-an-n-dimensional-hypersphere).

```
clear all 
clc

m = 20000;
n = 2; 
r = 2; 

%// generate circle boundary
C = [3 4]; %// center [x y]
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
x = r*cos(t) + C(1);
y = r*sin(t) + C(2);

C_rep = repmat( C,m,1);
X = randn(m,n);
s2 = sum(X.^2,2);
X = X.*repmat(r*(rand(m,1).^(1/n))./sqrt(s2),1,n)+ C_rep; 

%% Plot
figure(1), clf 
plot(x,y,'b')
hold on
plot(C(1),C(2),'r.', 'MarkerSize', 50) % center point
hold on


plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'g.','markersize',2); 
axis equal;zoom off; zoom on;drawnow;shg; 
ax = axis;
```

This is the output:

[image: img]

which is not what I want.

1. How to make the points distributed around a center point **C**?

   When `n = 2, 3, 4, k` dimentions
2. What does `s2` mean?

Comment: I think `s2` is the distance of random point to center powered by 2 for the inside hypersphere test. What you want to achieve? More density near center and low near surface?

Comment: Are the points not already centered about an arbitrary point?

Comment: I will use same code, but, I want to know what does s2 exactly mean?
Also, when n>2 does this line is correct?
X = X.*repmat(r*(rand(m,1).^(1/n))./sqrt(s2),1,n)+ C_rep;